# Cast a variable name to a new type permanently

Tags: java, types, casting

**I know that this isn't a good idea, for a whole host of reasons**, but if I have something like:

```
Dog s = new ShihTzu();
s.beCute();

   Error: line 2 - cannot find symbol - method beCute()

((ShihTzu) s).beCute();

   It's adorable!
```

In the same scope as `Dog s`, can I permanently re-cast the variable name `s` to be of type `ShihTzu`?

Or is it completely impossible? Once a variable has been defined of a type, then, in its current scope, there's no way to change it?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're after, but you can declare another variable `ShihTzu x = (ShihTzu) s;`.

Comment: "*Once a variable has been defined of a type, then, in its current scope, there's no way to change it?*" exactly.

Comment: @Sweeper - Yup, I know that, but I'm interested in re-using the variable name.

Comment: @jsheeran - I don't really, I'm just curious if the compiler will allow it in any which way. More just curiosity as opposed to a real world use. :)

Comment: @Jack_Hu Note that even if you use another variable name, the _object_ inside the new variable is still the same object as the one in `s`.

Comment: ... Or is there a way to *destroy* a variable name (other than assigning it to null, and calling `System.gc();`)?

Comment: @Jack_Hu that won't work either. GC is runtime, not compile time.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca - Of course! Wasn't thinking there... :P So there is absolutely no way of *getting back* a variable name?

Comment: @Jack_Hu What do you mean get back?  By utilizing different scopes you can use the same "name" for a variable, or you can overshadow a class field with a local variable for example too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible. When you declare a variable to be of a certain type, that can't be changed.

The Java spec [says](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4):

> It is a compile-time error if the name of a formal parameter is used to declare a new variable within the body of the method, constructor, or lambda expression, unless the new variable is declared within a class declaration contained by the method, constructor, or lambda expression.
>
> It is a compile-time error if the name of a local variable v is used to declare a new variable within the scope of v, unless the new variable is declared within a class whose declaration is within the scope of v.